# chrome android video full screen black flickr

Tags: android, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, fullscreen

I hooked camera stream on my mobile phone to html video tag, when I go videotag.webkitRequestFullscreen (for Chrome 34 Android), I get fullscreen but it's black and flickrs ( I see controls though).
Firefox for android works ok (mozRequestFullscreen), Chrome 34 desktop works ok.
Did anybody have similar problem ?
Why is this happening?